# Reactive extensions dispose event handler

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Hi guys I have a ExternalDataService that is constantly firing real time data, it is contained in a lib.

I have a wrapper class that subscribes and puts the  updates on a Observable..

```
   public class MyService
    {
        private ExternalDataService _externalDataService;

    public MyService()
    {
        _externalDataService= new ExternalDataService ();
    }


    public IObservable<double> GetData()
    {
        return Observable.Create<double>(i => 
        {   
            _externalPriceService.OnDataChanged += (s, e) => { i.OnNext(e); };


            return () => 
            {
              //  what do I do here?
            };
        });
    }    

}
```

Consumed as...

```
var p = new MyService();

var disposable = p.GetData().Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

How would I unsubscribe from  `_externalPriceService.OnDataChanged` when the `Dispose` is called on disposable?

Answer (score 3):

Use Observable.FromEvent or Observable.FromEventPattern, instead of Observable.Create.  Then you just Dispose the subscription.

Depending on your EventHandler definition, it would be something like this:

```
public class ExternalDataService {
    public EventHandler<DataChangedEventArgs> OnDataChanged;    
}

public class DataChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public Double Data {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class MyService {
    private ExternalDataService _externalDataService;
    public MyService()
    {
        _externalDataService= new ExternalDataService ();
    }
    public IObservable<double> GetData()
    {
        return Observable.FromEventPattern<DataChangedEventArgs>(eh => _externalDataService.OnDataChanged += eh, eh => _externalDataService.OnDataChanged -= eh)
            .Select(e => e.EventArgs.Data);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, would you mind showing me an example using my snippet above? THanks

Comment: @Andy Experiment on your own a bit, look through the documentation for the methods listed, and do some searching for existing examples.  If, after doing that, you are still having problems then edit the question (or ask a new one) to incorporate what you've tried, and why it didn't work.

Comment: @Andy Updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like this:

```
public IObservable<double> GetData()
{
    Action<object, double> dataHandler = null;
    return Observable.Create<double>(i => 
    {   
        dataHandler = (s, e) => { i.OnNext(e); };;
        _externalDataService.OnDataChanged += dataHandler;
        return Disposable.Create(() => 
        {
            _externalDataService.OnDataChanged -= dataHandler;
        });
    });
}
```

edit: stupid typos